# Add customer as recipient to woocommerce subscriptions cancelled subscription email (notification)

Tags: woocommerce, email-notifications, woocommerce-subscriptions

By default woocommerce subscriptions send the email notification that a subscription has been cancelled only to the admin of the store, NOT to the customer. This is not user friendly. I am trying to add the customer as a recipient to this specific email notification, without success so far.

I have tried writing add a filter with PhP to the action cancelled_subscription_notification . Which i believe handles the email notification for cancelled subscriptions.

```
add_filter( 'cancelled_subscription_notification', 
'wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email', 10, 2 );
function wc_cancelled_order_add_customer_email( $recipient, $order ){
// Avoiding errors in backend (mandatory when using $order argument)
if ( ! is_a( $order, 'WC_Order' ) ) return $recipient;

  // Get the customer ID
$user_id = $order->get_user_id();

// Get the user data
$user_data = get_userdata( $user_id );

return $recipient;
}
```

When using this code (added in functions.php) i get an error 500 when i cancel a subscription (the actual email to admin is also not send!).

Useful maybe: https://github.com/wp-premium/woocommerce-subscriptions/blob/master/includes/emails/class-wcs-email-cancelled-subscription.php (link to cancelled-subscription calls)

Answer (score 0):

this works for me. I was doing it in woocommerce_subscription_status_updated, but that causes an exception error with missing parent_id somehow.

```
`// send customer email on subscription updated
add_filter('woocommerce_email_recipient_cancelled_subscription', 'set_customer_as_cancelled_subscription_recipient', 10, 2);
function set_customer_as_cancelled_subscription_recipient($recipient, $subscription) {
    return $subscription ? $subscription->get_billing_email() : $recipient;
}`
```